# when grid to be print it show the child column which is hidden in extjs4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs4

I am using the grid. when able to print using Ed spenser's grid printer to print the grid. It show the child column in the print preview which has hidden actually.

for print

### snippet

```
print: function(grid) {
            var columns = [];
            for(var index in grid.columns) {
                var column = grid.columns[index];
                console.log(column);
                console.log("column.isVisible()-->"+column.isVisible());
                if(column.isVisible()) {
                    console.log("column.items.length:"+column.items.length);
                    console.log("column.items.visible:"+column.items.items);
                    if(!column.items.length) {
                        columns.push(column);
                    } else {
                        columns = columns.concat(column.items.items);
                    }
                }
            }

            var data = [];
            grid.store.data.each(function(item) {
                var convertedData = [];
                for(var key in item.data) {
                    var value = item.data[key];
                    Ext.each(columns, function(column) {
                        if(column.dataIndex == key) {
                            convertedData[key] = column.renderer ? column.renderer.call(grid, value, {}, item) : value;
                        }
                    }, this);
                }
                data.push(convertedData);

    });
```

### grid

```
Ext.apply(this, {
            store: App.mcmTaskStore,
            columnLines: true,
            columns: [
                { header: 'P', sortable: false, width: 25, dataIndex: 'Priority', renderer: priorityRenderer }, //false because it's H M L and it sorts alphabetically
                { header: 'START', sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'StartDateFormatted', hidden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer},
                { 
                    header: 'Incoming Flights',
                    columns: [
                        { header: 'FLT', sortable: true, width: 80, dataIndex: 'IncomingFlightNumber', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'ETA', sortable: true, width: 120, dataIndex: 'IncomingFlightEta', renderer: startDateCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'CTY', sortable: true, width: 60, dataIndex: 'IncomingFlightStation', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'GT', sortable: true, width: 50, dataIndex: 'IncomingFlightGate', hidden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer}
                    ]
                },
                { header: 'END', sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'EndDateFormatted', hidden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer},
                {
                    text: 'Outgoing Flights',
                    columns: [
                        { header: 'FLT', sortable: true, width: 80, dataIndex: 'OutgoingFlightNumber', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'ETD', sortable: true, width: 120, dataIndex: 'OutgoingFlightEtd', renderer: endDateCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'CTY', sortable: true, width: 60, dataIndex: 'OutgoingFlightStation', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                        { header: 'GT', sortable: true, width: 50, dataIndex: 'OutgoingFlightGate', hidden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer}
                    ]
                },
                { header: 'PAX NAME', sortable: true, width: 250, dataIndex: 'Name', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                { header: 'COMMENTS', sortable: false, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'Notes', hidden: true, renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer},
                { header: 'AGENT NAME', sortable: true, width: 250, dataIndex: 'AgentName', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer },
                { header: 'TASK TYPE', sortable: true, width: 120, dataIndex: 'TaskType', renderer: this.mcmCustomRenderer }
            ],
            tbar: mcmTbar
        });
```

Comment: @rixo can you help me please how to disable the child items in grid in print

Comment: @weeksdev please help me how to proceed??

Comment: @existdissolve please help me how to do when print the grid

Comment: @rixo this is the problem can you correct it..the problem is even the GT header inside incoming and outgoing flights is hidden but actually it shows in grid printer view..even am check the hidden column before print

Comment: Is the issue that it is flagging a column visible when it is, in fact, hidden? If so, does changing `if(column.isVisible())` to `if(!column.isHidden())` resolve the issue? Here is a reference to the isHidden() method on [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-isHidden)

Comment: Thanks @weeksdev Please give me any snippet example. am new to extjs

Comment: do you have some example json that i could use to create an example?  I'd like to try to create a fiddle for the issue.

Comment: @weeksdev I don't.have am using java spring integration with db as backend..in front end using Ajax and jsonp to fetch d data..

Comment: i mean the `json response` (for demonstration purposes doesn't have to be the real data just similar) that is received via the `ajax call`